# Unsecure content on https page in all browsers for website with SSL

Tags: magento, ssl, https

Having a bit of a mare trying to get SSL to work on secure pages of a Magento website.

Please visit https://www.showermania.co.uk/checkout/onepage/

Browsers alert visitors to unsecure content on the page and subsequently the green bar is not showing as it should for the certification.

If you check that page using http://www.whynopadlock.com, it is coming up with all sorts of things yet viewing the source shows everything as pulled in via https.

I'm really unsure what is required to make everything on the page load securely (as it seems to be already).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check how to install SSL in Magento here: http://magentocommerce.timpletcher.com/?p=36

Comment: SSL is setup in Magento correctly - this is related to the certificate itself.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate associated is not created in a secure chain of certification.

E.g. you ask to verisign or whoever you choose to buy the certificate, they have two or three digital signatures in order to prove a certificate as valid, then is the certificate itself saying that your site is hosted there and, if you have a pro version, that your company is running that site.

If you created it by yourself, it means your closed certification authority is not in the browser's list of trusted sources. 
If someone else created it for you, perhaps you are missing some steps in the process because you need to install some extra certificate in order to validate the chain of certification correctly. Check in their instructions.

EDIT: Checking in comodo, found some info about installation, which you should check depending on the version you bought. Check [how to install](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=view&parentcategoryid=95&pcid=1&nav=0,96,1&key5sk1=11b7b3309f676bf952f1e24f7d4eb34ba81cc98a&key5sk2=2128&key5sk3=1344271817000&key5sk4=2128&key5sk5=1344271837000&key5sk6=1904&key5sk7=1344271872000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=FF110&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=es-es&key6sk5=CO&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=Google&key6sk9=1366768&key6sk10=false&key6sk11=0f02e414c577aabd7f399b1fb513bc31e2e5bc1b&key6sk12=2032&key7sk1=2&key7sk2=196112&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google) and indications about [root and intermediate certificates](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1182).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The certificate was purchased from one of the biggest providers of SSL certification (Comodo). It was installed by our web host. I didn't create it myself at all. It's one of the more expensive ones as well. Don't know if this responds to your answer at all? Thanks

Comment: Edited already, please check the whole answer again. Also, I see now you did install the intermediate certs and it works fine... but now your site is redirecting to http :( keep working it!

Comment: Thanks Alfabravo. Instructions were followed from Comodo (who are almost completely useless may I add) although I will revisit the installation looking at that second link you posted and report back once I've gone through everything. Thanks very much for your time.